# Type error : an integer is required (got type datetime. datetime)

Tags: python

I am striping the time and doing subtraction with that time and today time  but getting type error
Can anyone please help me

```
import datetime
date_time= '22-06- 
24T05:31:06.000+00'
txt=date_time.strip("T
05:31:06.000+00")     
date_time_obj=datetime.datetime
.strptime(txt, '%y-%m-%d')
Sub=datetime.date(date_time_obj) 
Today=datetime.date.today() 
Actual=Today-Sub
Print(Actual)
```

Comment: The formatting is unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `date_time_obj` to date with `.date()` function:

```
import datetime
date_time= '22-06-24T05:31:06.000+00'
txt=date_time.strip("T05:31:06.000+00")     
date_time_obj=datetime.datetime.strptime(txt, '%y-%m-%d')
Sub=date_time_obj.date()
Today=datetime.date.today()
Actual=Today-Sub
print(Actual)
```

**Output:**

```
5 days, 0:00:00
```

Comment: if the output  is 5 days or in between 5 days add in list else don't add how to do that could you help me

Comment: @chandrika-donepudi Use `append()` function to add values to list and an if statement